# How do I style Labels with NativeScript Vue? Document example isn't working

Tags: css, mobile, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a simple GridLayout

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *, *" rows="100">
            <Label id="all-sales" text="0,0" row="0" col="0" style="background-color: blue"/>
            <Label text="a,1" row="0" col="1" class="links" backgroundColor="blue" />
            <Label text="0,1" row="0" col="3" class="links"/>
        </GridLayout>
```

Note I have three labels that I am trying to style.  The first uses an inline style, the second the what the NativeScript Docs call javascript property, and the last one with a class.
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling

The only one that works is the javascript property.

[image]
This is an image of the iOS simulator.

I assuming I missing something because styling is in every example I've seen but it doesn't seem to work?

This is what I am running...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/theme": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^8.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~8.0.0",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.7.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: Is your issue that background color not being applied on first label?

Comment: Yes, I expected all three would be blue.

Comment: It works on my end, can you try setting up a Playground where the issue can be reproduced.